# IText is not able to search word from pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

We are trying to search word from PDF. Itext sharp is not able to search it. It gave us some good results but not all. Some of the words are not able to search.

Example: There is a word in PDF "Kasserman" but it is not found by IText where as adobe and chrome is able to read it. 
In addition if I search form "Kasserm" or "Kasserm an" it got the result. As it is considering a space between word. 
Please check this example in [PDF here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9b-BPJeVcfyZ09sTTNmekJfM28/view?usp=sharing)

I set lot of good strategies of IText sharp but still found these type of errors. Please provide me a possible solution.

Comment: Can you provide some code sample?

Comment: IText does not have an explicit "search" functionality. Thus, it is not clear how *exactly* you used iText to search the words. If you want help, therefore, please share the pivotal code.

Comment: *where as adobe and chrome is able to read it* - I cannot reproduce that. Here Adobe Reader also finds "Kasserm" but not "Kasserma". Furthermore, if you move the cursor step by step along the *Kasserman* in the text, you'll see that there is a small extra step between "m" and "a". You should be aware that your document is an image that is OCR'ed, and OCR'ed images often contain little errors. Thus, if you want to search in them, you should not simply search the exact phrase you look for in the extracted text but allow for some differences, e.g. added or missing spaces.

Comment: MKL, I agree with you that this may OCR mistake. but as while OCR this image to PDF, I also make a text file and this contain no space between them. but while searching using IText this didn't work. I am sending code over [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwGGVJUtdTGSWQ5X3p1V21sUzA/view?usp=sharing).